# Hashmap order inside the expandable listview varies from device to another

Tags: switch-statement, expandablelistview, linkedhashmap, dataprovider

Now i'm making an application that it should display a list of courses in an expandable list view and when the user clicks on a child element it opens a new activity with the course details , everything works pretty fine but , when i tested the application through nexus the order of the courses was the same i put inside the hashmap and in the switch case statement but when i tested it through my galaxy not two here it came the disaster the orders in the list were scrambled so the click event got messed up when supposed to open course details for x it opens for y and so on ,,, what should i do ?

**THIS IS THE MAIN**

```
public class Courses extends ActionBarActivity {


    HashMap<String,List<String>> Courses_castegory;

    List<String> Courses_list;

    ExpandableListView expandableListView;

    MyCourseAdapter myCourseAdapter;

    Intent detaledActivity;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_courses);

        expandableListView = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.simple_expandable_list);
        Courses_castegory = CourseProvider.getInfo();
        Courses_list=new ArrayList<>(Courses_castegory.keySet());//get all the keys from the hashmap

        myCourseAdapter = new MyCourseAdapter(this,Courses_castegory,Courses_list);

        expandableListView.setAdapter(myCourseAdapter);


        expandableListView.setOnGroupCollapseListener(new ExpandableListView.OnGroupCollapseListener() {
            @Override
            public void onGroupCollapse(int groupPosition) {
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), Courses_list.get(groupPosition) + " is collapsed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

        expandableListView.setOnChildClickListener(new ExpandableListView.OnChildClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v, int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) {


                //Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),
                //Courses_castegory.get(Courses_list.get(groupPosition)).get(childPosition)+" from "+Courses_list.get(groupPosition)+" is selected",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                switch(groupPosition) {
                    case 0:
                        switch (childPosition) {
                            case 0:
                                detaledActivity = new Intent(Courses.this, DetailedCouse.class);
                                startActivity(detaledActivity);
                                break;

                        }
                }

                return true;
            }
        });

    }




    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_courses, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }





}
```

**THIS IS THE COURSE PROVIDER**

```
public class CourseProvider {

public static HashMap<String,List<String>> getInfo(){
    HashMap<String,List<String>>CourseDetails = new HashMap<String,List<String>>();

    List<String> CourseType1 = new ArrayList<>();
    CourseType1.add("English For Work");


    List<String> CourseType2= new ArrayList<>();
    CourseType2.add("General English For Work");
    CourseType2.add("Intensive English For Work");

    List<String> CourseType3 = new ArrayList<>();
    CourseType3.add("English Academic Year");
    CourseType3.add("English Academic Semester");

    List<String> CourseType4 = new ArrayList<>();
    CourseType4.add("IELTS Exam Preparation");
    CourseType4.add("TOEFL Exam Preparation");
    CourseType4.add("GMAT Exam Preparation");
    CourseType4.add("GRE Exam Preparation");

    List<String> CourseType5 = new ArrayList<>();
    CourseType5.add("Young Learners");

    List<String> CourseType6 = new ArrayList<>();
    CourseType6.add("General English Language");
    CourseType6.add("Intensive English Language");
    CourseType6.add("30+");

    CourseDetails.put("Learn English in Your Teacher's Home",CourseType1);
    CourseDetails.put("English For Work",CourseType2);
    CourseDetails.put("Academic Semester / Year",CourseType3);
    CourseDetails.put("Exam Preparation Courses",CourseType4);
    CourseDetails.put("Young Learners",CourseType5);
    CourseDetails.put("Flexible Courses",CourseType6);

    return CourseDetails;
}}
```

**AND THIS IS THE COURSE ADAPTER**

```
public class MyCourseAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {

private Context context;
private HashMap<String,List<String>>Courses_Category;
private List<String> Course_List ;


public MyCourseAdapter(Context context ,HashMap<String,List<String>>Courses_Category,List<String> Course_List) {

    this.context=context;
    this.Courses_Category=Courses_Category;
    this.Course_List=Course_List;


}



@Override
public int getGroupCount() {
    return Course_List.size();
}

@Override
public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
    return Courses_Category.get(Course_List.get(groupPosition)).size();

}

@Override
public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
    return Course_List.get(groupPosition);
}

@Override
public Object getChild(int parent, int child) {
    return Courses_Category.get(Course_List.get(parent)).get(child);
}

@Override
public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
    return groupPosition;
}

@Override
public long getChildId(int parent, int child) {
    return child;
}

@Override
public boolean hasStableIds() {
    return false;
}

@Override
public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    String group_title = (String) getGroup(groupPosition);
    if (convertView==null){
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.parent_courses,parent,false);

    }


    TextView parent_textview = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.parent_text_view);
    parent_textview.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
    parent_textview.setText(group_title);

    return convertView;

}

@Override
public View getChildView(final int parentPosition, final int childPosition, boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    String child_title = (String) getChild(parentPosition,childPosition);

    if (convertView==null){
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        convertView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.child_courses,parent,false);

    }

    TextView child_textview = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.child_text_view);
    child_textview.setText(child_title);

    return convertView;
}

@Override
public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    return true;
}

public void onGroupCollapsed(int groupPosition){
    super.onGroupCollapsed(groupPosition);
}
public void onGroupExpanded(int groupPosition){
    super.onGroupExpanded(groupPosition);
}}
//
```

Answer (score 1):

Done using `LinkedHashMap`instead of `HashMap`